# Multiplication of congruence classes modulo an ideal : $(\mathfrak{p}+(x))(\mathfrak{p}+(y))=\mathfrak{p}+(xy)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

$(\mathfrak{p}+(x)).(\mathfrak{p}+(y))\subseteq\mathfrak{p}+(xy)$ is rather straightforward to show considering the elements of the ideals on the left and definition of sum and product of ideals. Here $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of a commutative ring $A$, and $A\ni x,y\not\in \mathfrak{p}$.

I was wondering if I could lift this problem to the quotient ring $A/\mathfrak{p}$ and then use that $(a).(b)=(ab)$ and use the ring/ideal correspondence theorem to get back to this problem in ring $A$ and conclude something like $(\mathfrak{p}+(x))(\mathfrak{p}+(y))=\mathfrak{p}+(xy)$. Here is what I have tried.

$\pi(\mathfrak{p}+(x))=(\mathfrak{p}+(x))/\mathfrak{p}$ where $\pi:A\to A/\mathfrak{p}$ is the canonical map. An element in $(\mathfrak{p}+(x))/\mathfrak{p}$ is of the form $ax+\mathfrak{p}=a(x+\mathfrak{p})$ for some $a\in A$. Hence, $(\mathfrak{p}+(x))/\mathfrak{p}=(x+\mathfrak{p})\subseteq A/\mathfrak{p}$. Similarly, $\mathfrak{p}+(y)$ gets mapped to $(y+\mathfrak{p})\subseteq A/\mathfrak{p}$. So, $(x+\mathfrak{p}).(y+\mathfrak{p})=(xy+\mathfrak{p})$.

Since $\pi^{-1}(\pi(I))=I+\mathfrak{p}$ for any $I\subseteq A$ ideal, I want to take (not sure if this makes sense) $\pi^{-1}$ throughout $(x+\mathfrak{p}).(y+\mathfrak{p})=(xy+\mathfrak{p})$ and claim that $(\mathfrak{p}+(x)).(\mathfrak{p}+(y))=\mathfrak{p}+(xy)$.

I think my confusion is about how to go from $A$ to $A/\mathfrak{p}$ and then come back to $A$ again. I am still very wobbly in using the correspondence theorem and playing around with $\pi$, I would really appreciate if someone can point out any mistakes.

Comment: I think the issue is that $\pi^{-1}$ doesn't preserve products

Comment: I'm confused. How could the quotient ring possibly be a ring if you didn't have multiplication of congruence classes? 


I believe you're trying to show that multiplication of congruence classes module $\mathfrak{p}$ is well-defined. If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, I don't think you should use the quotient ring to do it, because that's circular. 


What I would do is show that congrunce modulo $\mathfrak{p}$ is an equivalence relation, and so if $(x + \mathfrak{p})(y+\mathfrak{p}) \subseteq xy + \mathfrak{p}$, then in fact they are equal.

Comment: @LukasHeger Any suggestions on how to do that?